# Function returning same list twice

Tags: python, list

UPDATED AFTER FRESH EXAMINATION
I created a function, below, that takes in a list of strings, where the strings are sentences each having a varying number of words. 
I then try to break those strings down into their individual words, using item.split(), creating a new list with words rather than sentences.
Then I try to print the length of the new list.

I am passing in a list called `split_list` which is defined outside of this function and is a list of strings (list of sentences).

Here is how I create `split_list` based on a .txt file which is itself one long string in its original form.

```
file = open("classic_cars.txt", "r")
split_list = []
for line in file:
    new_list = line.split(".")
    ultra_list = line.split("?")
    split_list.extend(new_list)
    split_list.extend(ultra_list)
#print(split_list)
```

The Problem: I did a manual word count on my text file and it shows as having 957 words. However when I print length of my returned/newly generated list, it is showing as 1917. When I print the new_list to the console, it is printing it twice. Why is it doing that?

```
def create_list_with_words(list):
  new_list = []
  for item in list:
     words = item.split()
     for word in words:
         new_list.append(word)
  print(new_list)
  print(len(new_list))

create_list_of_words(split_list)
```

Comment: Take a small input sentence and show us what the output should be and what you are getting.

Comment: You are probably getting duplicates. Maybe use a set.

Comment: @HarshalParekh Thanks. I just tried your suggestion and it works perfectly for a small input sentence.  I will update my question where I create the split_list, as it now seems the issue must be there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It is indeed giving me back a duplicate of the list. Do you know why it is doing that? I am creating a new list which starts out as an empty list?

Comment: @HarshalParekh the issue is not where I create split_list. I have updated question. The news is that it prints out the new list with separated words twice.

Comment: In your first block of code, you split each line _twice_. Once on `'.'` and once on `'?'`. Then you add _both_ of those lists to `split_list` - resulting in the doubling of the words. What is that code trying to do?

Comment: ahah. That code is trying to split the string into sentences for when sentences end in full stop, or for when they end in question mark. Split doesn't seem to take two parameters. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: You can use regex. `import re` then `split_list.extend(re.split(r"[?\.]\s*", line))`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just implemented this and finally after so long this is working. Regex is new to me so I will move on to next part in the program and come back to this later so I can understand what it's doing. Huge thanks again.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Hi again. Just wondering, did you mean to use a forward slash '/' instead of backward slash in [?\.]"? Or is the backslash correct? I ask because pycharm is highlighting it with faded highlight. The other thing is, will this include the '?' in the string, because right now going through the items is not reading the '?'

Comment: The backslash is correct, although it is not actually not needed in this case. (The dot is a special character in regex so I escaped it but it doesn't need to be escaped here.) Make sure you put the "r" in front of the string - this marks it as a "raw" string where backslashes don't need to be escaped.  Maybe pycharm is not reading the "r'?

Comment: I've copied it in exactly as you have it here with the "r" included. Pycharm is only highlighting the part inside the string after this r: `r"[?.]\s*"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicates you are getting are because you are trying to split the same line twice with two different characters.

For e.g., consider the following line:

> I am trying to learn python. Am I really? This is the sentence I will
>   test.

If we pass this line to your for loop it will split this line as follows:

> **First on . (dot)**

```py
new_list = ['I am trying to learn python', ' Am I really? This is the sentence I will test', '']
```

> **Second time on ? (Question Mark)**

```py
ultra_list = ['I am trying to learn python. Am I really', ' This is the sentence I will test.']
```

You extend these two lists to `split_list` as follows:

```py
split_list.extend(new_list)
split_list.extend(ultra_list)
```

So the final `split_list` will be:

```py
split_list = ['I am trying to learn python', ' Am I really? This is the sentence I will test', '', 'I am trying to learn python. Am I really', ' This is the sentence I will test.']
```

This list you are passing to your function `create_list_with_words`, which runs through each element of the `split_list` and split each element on space. So the wrong count.

Following is the corrected code:

```py
def create_list_with_words(list):
  new_list = []
  for item in list:
     words = item.split()
     for word in words:
         new_list.append(word)
  print(new_list)
  print(len(new_list))

file = open("classic_cars.txt", "r")
split_list = []
for line in file:
    line = line.replace("?", '')
    new_list = line.split(".")
    split_list.extend(new_list)

create_list_with_words(split_list)
```

You might have to make more tweaks in this code depending on your need.

**NOTE:** Your function name is `create_list_with_words` but the call given as `create_list_of_words`. I am assuming it as typo while posting.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. The only thing is that I need to keep the '?' in the text. And I think that line = line.replace("?", '') would replace the ? with an empty space? If so, is there another way using replace or split?

Comment: Your code is also removing it using split. So, if you need to keep `?` in the text but need to separate it from the word, you can use the same replace but the replacement text would be ' ? ', this will keep the `?` at the same time separate it from the word. The line will be like: line = line.replace("?", ' ? ')